# Docker ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf'

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I've looked through several websites but I can't seem to find an answer.
I'm new to django and docker and whilist building my first project which is a quotation generator, I've been looking for different ways to generate a pdf for each quote.

I found a couple of tutorials on **xhtml2pdf** and my error appears when I try to run
 `docker-compose up` and get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xhtml2pdf'`

I've installed **xhtml2pdf** using `pip3 install xhtml2pdf`
and whenever I try to run it again I get:
`Requirement already satisfied: xhtml2pdf`, the same for its dependencies.

I've also tried `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall xhtml2pdf` with no luck

on my *views.py* file if I write `from xhtml2pdf import pisa` vs code gives me no errors regarding the import

My *requirements.txt* lookslike this:

```
psycopg2==2.9.1
pillow>=8.3
xhtml2pdf==0.2.5
reportlab==3.6.1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code


COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to build the image first after you added new packages in your requirements.txt to get them installed. Simply running `docker-compose up` will just run the image you previously built. Surely that image does not contain the new pip package `xhtmltopdf`

use

```
docker-compose build
```

then

```
docker-compose up
```

or you can use the following command to do it at once

```
docker-compose up --build
```

If you want to build the image entirely from scratch use

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Comment: Thans, that helped!